# AutoHotKey: how to check if the copy/paste buffer has certain phrase or keyword and act upon result

Tags: autohotkey

After about two years from my initial question, I keep finding myself needing a screen scraping from a browser window.

The way I do this is :
Maximize the browser window with

```
send !{space}
sleep 500
send x
```

then, place the cursor close to top left corner with

```
mousemove, 30, 30 ; or similar 
sleep 250 ; let computer catch up with mouse movement
mouseclick, L
send ^a
sleep 250
send ^c
```

at this point. I have the screen-scraped content in my paste buffer. All I am interested in is the text portions anyway. I can launch a notepad and paste the contents of the buffer into a text file and try searching for the the strings I am looking for, but I have gut feeling that, I can skip this temporary file creation step. Just don't know how.

And I would like to perform, few more ahk commands if the string is found in the buffer or keep waiting looping if it is not there yet.

Thanks for your contributions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you look for the string *Hello World* in your clipboard
an example code would be

```
send ^c

StringCaseSense, Off
Haystack = %Clipboard%
Needle = Hello World
IfInString, Haystack, %Needle%
{
    MsgBox, The string was found.
    return
} 
else
{
;Do something else here
}
```

Comment: exactly what I am looking for. Haven't tested yet but I will as soon as I get home this evening. Although it looks pretty simple enough to cause any problem. BTW, needle/haystack analogy was pretty nifty and funny too. Thanks for the chuckle...

Answer (score 1):

You an use the built in variable 'Clipboard' to read and write the clipboard contents.